# How to pass a Tumblr class object via ajax

Tags: php, ajax, tumblr

How do you reference a class object that is created in one php file in another php file called via ajax?

I have a project that uses Tumblr's API to make posts to a blog

There are 2 files: `tumblr.php` and `ajaxTumblr.php`

In `tumblr.php`, a Tumblr object is created:

```
include_once ("Tumblr/API/Client.php");
include_once ("Tumblr/API/RequestException.php");
include_once ("Tumblr/API/RequestHandler.php");

$consumerKey = "xxxxxx";
$consumerSecret = "xxxxxx";

$client = new Tumblr\API\Client($consumerKey, $consumerSecret);
$requestHandler = $client->getRequestHandler();
$requestHandler->setBaseUrl('https://www.tumblr.com/');
```

Then it goes through the oauth sequence, ending up with `$client` fully populated with the access token & token_secret. I omitted the code for this, since it's likely not relevant.

Now the user is validated and I can do stuff like display the user's info

`$info = $client->getUserInfo();`

Or even make a post with some preset data.

```
$postData = array('title' => $title, 'body' => $body, 'format' => $format);
$client->createPost($userid, $postData);
```

So far, so good.

Now I collect data from the user (title & blog text) via textareas and send an ajax request to `ajaxTumblr.php` with this info

```
        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://domain.com/ajaxTumblr.php',
            type:'POST',
            async: "false",
            data: {'title': title,
                'body': body,
                'userid': userid,
                'state': "draft",
                'format': "html" },
            success: function (res) {
                console.log (res);
            } 
        });
```

Here's where I am stuck.

How do we pass over, reference or recreate `$client` in the ajax php file?  I can't generate a new Tumblr object, since it requires user authorization.

I'd like to have my code perform something like:

```
$title = $_REQUEST['title'];
$body = $_REQUEST['body'];
$format = $_REQUEST['format'];
$userid = $_REQUEST['userid'];

$postData = array('title' => $title, 'body' => $body, 'format' => $format);
$client->createPost($userid, $postData);
```

Thanks.

**Update**

In `Tumblr.php`, I saved `$client`:

`$_SESSION['client'] = serialize($client);`

And then in `ajaxTumblr.php` created a new object and copied the original object to the new one.  Is this okay to do?

```
include_once ("Tumblr/API/Client.php");
include_once ("Tumblr/API/RequestException.php");
include_once ("Tumblr/API/RequestHandler.php");

// OAuth Consumer Key:
$consumerKey = "xxxxxxx";
$consumerSecret = "xxxxxxxx";
$ajaxClient = new Tumblr\API\Client($consumerKey, $consumerSecret);

$client = unserialize($_SESSION['client']);
$ajaxClient = $client;
```

When I reran the test, thousands of errors were thrown from one of the class modules complaining about parameters being incorrect.  I might be on the right path, but need conformation.

```
[04-Oct-2015 14:46:27 America/Chicago] PHP Warning:  curl_multi_add_handle() expects parameter 1 to be resource, integer given in /home3/me/vendor/guzzle/guzzle/src/Guzzle/Http/Curl/CurlMulti.php on line 181 
[04-Oct-2015 14:46:27 America/Chicago] PHP Warning:  curl_multi_exec() expects parameter 1 to be resource, integer given in /home3/me/vendor/guzzle/guzzle/src/Guzzle/Http/Curl/CurlMulti.php on line 238 
[04-Oct-2015 14:46:27 America/Chicago] PHP Warning:  curl_multi_info_read() expects parameter 1 to be resource, integer given in /home3/me/vendor/guzzle/guzzle/src/Guzzle/Http/Curl/CurlMulti.php on line 254 
[04-Oct-2015 14:46:27 America/Chicago] PHP Warning:  curl_multi_exec() expects parameter 1 to be resource, integer given in /home3/me/vendor/guzzle/guzzle/src/Guzzle/Http/Curl/CurlMulti.php on line 238 
[04-Oct-2015 14:46:27 America/Chicago] PHP Warning:  curl_multi_info_read() expects parameter 1 to be resource, integer given in /home3/me/vendor/guzzle/guzzle/src/Guzzle/Http/Curl/CurlMulti.php on line 254 
[04-Oct-2015 14:46:27 America/Chicago] PHP Warning:  curl_multi_exec() expects parameter 1 to be resource, integer given in /home3/me/vendor/guzzle/guzzle/src/Guzzle/Http/Curl/CurlMulti.php on line 238
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Tumblr app settings, it asks you for "Default callback URL".  This is set to `"tumblr.php"`, so the app can perform authentication activities.

The problem seemed to arise when `ajaxTumblr.php` tries to perform API calls.  The callback does not equal the calling module.

Further, there was a slight discrepancy between the `$client` and `$ajaxClient` objects. There was a null resource in one of the elements, causing the errors shown above.

With these issues holding me back, I decided to ditch `ajaxTumblr.php` and have the URL in the ajax call point to `tumblr.php` (i.e. itself) and added some logic at the top to detect if this is a `$_POST` request.

As a result, the `$client` object is identical, and I managed to get the app to post to my Tumblr blog.

Here is a code snippet that I added in `tumblr.php`

```
if (isset($_POST['blogTitle'])){
    $token = $_SESSION['token'] ;
    $secret = $_SESSION['secret'] ;
    $client = new Tumblr\API\Client($consumerKey, $consumerSecret, $token, $secret);

    $blogName = $_POST['blogName']; 
    $blogTitle = $_POST['blogTitle'];
    $blogBody = $_POST['blogBody'];
    <snip>
    $postData = array('title' => $blogTitle, 'body' => $blogBody, 'format' => $format, 'state' => $state );
    $res = $client->createPost($blogName, $postData);

    exit;
}
```